# Saving excanvas element as image in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, image, screen-scraping, jqplot, excanvas

I am using IE7/8 for jqPlot for rendering canvas and would like to know if it is possible to print it out in jpg/png or any other format. I have been struggling with it from a long time and the only answer I got on web is nope.Is there any javaScript hack or screen scraping kinda tool which can help me to take an image of the graphs rendered on the canvas.Thanks

Comment: These versions of IE simply cannot rasterize VML graphics, so the only way to do this in IE7/8 would be to use a Flash-based solution line FxCanvas.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is a way to do this
http://westside-consulting.blogspot.com/2011/05/some-users-of-jqplot-have-expressed.html
go to this link nad you will be able to open the image in a new tab with this
var img = $wnd.jQuery('#' + id).jqplotToImage(50, 50);
        if (img) {
            open(img.toDataURL("image/jpg"));
        }

You can find the complete js in above link and I did this with GWT and it will be easy to do this in js I guess..Good luck..